# htm2canvas squishing text and not rendering changed background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a div configured with a background image when the page loads. It contains two p elements that are used to overlay text on the top and bottom of the image, like a meme. I have a selection of images that can be clicked and the background image of the div will change. That works fine.

html2canvas always renders the original, hard-coded background image no matter what image is currently configured for the background. When a new image is updated in the background image property, html2canvas always parses/renders the default image I have in CSS

The other problem is that the returned canvas seems compressed. The text is squished and overlaps.

When html2canvas is called, I remove p elements in the div because it was causing white space problems on the resulting canvas. I then append the canvas to the div. It works fine except for it not parsing the correct image and the text being compressed.

This is how I change the background image. I use event.target to get the image. This seems to work because the background image does change when I fire the event.

```
function changeImage(target) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
    rules[5].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + target.src + ")";
}
```

Here is how I generate the canvas. The meme div contains the two p elements. I remove both of them and append the canvas to the div. I expect nothing to change except the div is now a downloadable image due to the canvas.

```
function generateMeme(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('meme'), {scale: 1}).then(function(canvas) {
            document.getElementById('generate').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('top_text').value = ""
            document.getElementById('top_text').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('bottom_text').value = ""
            document.getElementById('bottom_text').disabled = true;
            var meme = document.getElementById('meme');
            meme.removeChild(meme.firstElementChild);
            meme.removeChild(meme.firstElementChild);
            meme.appendChild(canvas);
    })
}
```

When I create the canvas, the quality degrades a bit. The picture becomes a tad blurry. But the text issue is really noticeable; and obviously the wrong picture being used if it was changed.

If more code is needed to help fix this or you need to see my CSS, let me know.